# How to perform future cashflow projections using Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I am working on getting the future cashflows using SQL. It includes outstanding balance, standard payment, interest and Principal. Currently I have the report in excel but I need to get the exact same thing in Teradata.

I would like to divide my question into two parts:

1. Get the current balance and interest rates from the table (easy enough)
2. Generate future dates and project for the next 20 days (not sure how to do this)

I have tried windows functions till now but wasn't able to do it.

```
SELECT
   "Account Number"
   ,"Business Date"
   ,"Outstanding Balance"
   ,"Standard Payment" 
   ,"Current Balance" - "Standard Payment" "Dummy Balance" 
   ,MAX("Dummy Balance" ) OVER (PARTITION BY "Account Number" ORDER BY "Business    Date" ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING  )"Prev Balance"
FROM table
  where [<Conditions>]
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ORDER BY "NEXT DAYS";
```

[image]

As in the image, the ending balance goes back to the beginning balance field and the interest and principal are calculated based on this new beginning balance value.

For example, first row has beginning balance value as 100, the interest and principal is calculated on the basis of 100 and then subtracted from the beginning balance to get the ending balance which is 99.70200384. In the next row, this becomes the beginning balance and all the other values are calculated based on this.

Is this possible to do it in SQL?

Comment: So starting on your second row, you want the beginning balance to be the previous row's ending balance?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Use LAG or LEAD instead of MAX with your window function

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, the `ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING` accomplishes the same thing as lag.

Comment: I am stuck with this problem from few days. Could you please give me some idea on how to go about this problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show some base data, how does it look like? A singe row per account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some recursive SQL. Assuming you got one row per account and want to get the next 10 days:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
 (
   SELECT 
      account_number,
      Cast(100 AS DECIMAL(38,8)) AS balance,
      0.56466283 AS payment,
      0.00266666667 AS interest_rate,
      balance * interest_rate AS interest,
      payment - interest AS principal,
      balance - principal AS end_balance,
      Current_Date AS dt
   FROM mytable

   UNION ALL

   SELECT
      account_number,
      end_balance,
      payment,
      interest_rate,
      end_balance * interest_rate AS new_interest,
      payment - new_interest AS new_principal,
      end_balance - new_principal AS new_balance,
      dt+1 as new_dt
   FROM cte
   WHERE new_dt < Current_Date+10
 )
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
ORDER BY account_number, dt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I have a 'repayment date' field for every account and the customers repay every month. For example if the next repayment date is 15/06/2019, then I need to see the repayments for 15/07/2019, 15/08/2019 and so on till the maturity date. Could you tell me how to include that condition or just give me some direction? Thanks a mill for this again

Comment: Add a month instead of a day using `add_months(repayment_date, 1)` and compare it to the maturity date. Or filter for `where new_balance <= 0)`